# fetching data on the iphone

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, xml, json

Hey i am developing an iPhone app of a existing PhP mySQL website. i want to know, how to pull data from database and display on the phone?
after going through several articles , i found out two ways..

1) create a web service, on server end, which will provide all the data in XML format to the device.

2) export php,mysql data in JSON format, and pass this JSON data to the device, which will parse it..

are these two correct approaches??
if yes, which is easier and faster?

Comment: Any particular reason you are building an App? It tends to be alot faster and easier (and less chance of upsetting the Apple Warlords and their draconian approval process) to just build a web-application (ie HTML/PHP pages which are designed to display well on an iPhone) and access it through Safari.

Comment: but i want to explore more iOS gestures, movements..so lets see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a webservice from PHP to iPhone I suggest you to use JSON.
You can create a JSON response using json_encode (see manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)) and easily decode it on the device using SBJSon (you can download it [here](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/))